# Can we make our new top bar slightly transparent black, like our old one?

Tags: feature-request, design, top-bar

Our old topbar was slightly transparent, and a darker black:

[image]

(from the [Web Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20170223010444/http://scifi.stackexchange.com/))

Our new one, however, is not transparent, and is a lighter grayish black:

[image]

This means that we don't get the full advantage of our awesome design. It's a slightly lighter color, which means it blends in less, and, in my opinion brings down our looks slightly; and the top of the background is blocked by the topbar.

Editing the color to be straight black looks better:

[image]

But I still think it would be better if it was kind of transparent. Would this be possible?

Comment: Mis-matched blacks! The age-old fashion faux pas! Proportionately darker black would definitely be helpful design-wise.

Comment: +1, but I'm afraid of the designers looking at our starfield and thinking "Never use straight black!" and doing exactly the opposite of what you propose.